# Como envio por correo una parte del HTML de mi pagina

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, session, smtp

Necesito enviar por correo un recibo de una compra.

Digamos que se tiene una lista de items que el usuario desea comprar, deseo pasar por correo los datos de esa orden, Nombre de los items, descripcion y otros datos, cantidad, sub-total y el total.

Tengo un metodo el cual probe con un boton y me envia un correo con un mensaje ya creado de prueba en formato html:

```
public ActionResult ConfirmarOrden()
{
     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
     SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
     mail.From = new MailAddress("MICORREO@gmail.com");
     mail.To.Add("CORREODELCLIENTE@gmail.com");
     mail.Subject = "Nueva orden";
     mail.Body =
     "<table border striped><thead><tr><td>Preview</td><td>Name a Door</td><td>Outside profile</td><td>Inside profile</td><td>Flat Panel</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Sub-Total</td><td>Total Price</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><img src=@i.Picture></td><td>@i.Material.Description</td><td>@i.OutsideEdgeProfile.Description</td><td>@i.InsideEdgeProfile.Description</td><td>@i.PanelMaterial.Description</td><td>@i.Quantity</td></tr></tbody></table>";
      mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

      SmtpServer.Port = 800;
      SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MICORREO@gmail.com", "CLAVEDEMICORREO");
      SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
      SmtpServer.Send(mail);
      return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Entonces como haria para pasar por el `mail.Body` el html de mi pagina que contiene la orden que se esta procesando, o si hago la consulta a la bd sobre esa orden como envio luego eso por el correo.

Me gusta lo del formato en HTML porque el correo llega en un tabla muy ordenado y es lo que busco.

[image: Asi me llega al correo]

Comment: Como está en el ejemplo, tenes que escribir el html e integrarle los datos de tu base de datos en forma similar a cuando se genera el html que se devuelve desde el servidor al cliente. Solo que en lugar de devolverlo lo almacenas en una variable que viene a ser el body del email.

Comment: Aunque creo que si ya haz generado tu factura en la pagina obviamente estara generado en html y lo que puedes hacer es con ajax mandar la tabla con todo su contenido y en el servidor recibir esto como un parametro y tan solo asignarlo al body del correo

Comment: Exacto Denifer eso es lo que quiero, se como hacer el ajax para pasar los datos al controlador, lo que no se es como mandar la tabla con todo su contenido.